# Android FireBase change Listview order

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My application is returning the latest data from firebase to the buttom of the ListView. But I want it to be on the top! I have thought about it and I think there is only two possible ways to do it.

**1.** **Invert the Listview.**

I think that this way is how it should be done but I couldn't figure it out. I have searched a lot on the web but no suitable solution for my case 

This is my adapter code

```
 public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Setup our view and list adapter. Ensure it scrolls to the bottom as data changes
        final ListView listView = getListView();
        // Tell our list adapter that we only want 50 messages at a time
        mChatListAdapter = new ChatListAdapter(mFirebaseRef.limit(50), this, R.layout.chat_message, mUsername);
        listView.setAdapter(mChatListAdapter);
}
```

And this is the code for the `ChatListAdapter` constructor for a custom list class `ChatListAdapter` which extends special list adapter class `FirebaseListAdapter`:

```
public ChatListAdapter(Query ref, Activity activity, int layout, String mUsername) {
    super(ref, Chat.class, layout, activity);
    this.mUsername = mUsername;
}
```

**[Edit]** This is some of the code for `FirebaseListAdapter` which extends `BaseAdapter` class

```
 public FirebaseListAdapter(Query mRef, Class<T> mModelClass, int mLayout, Activity activity) {
    this.mRef = mRef;
    this.mModelClass = mModelClass;
    this.mLayout = mLayout;
    mInflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    mModels = new ArrayList<T>();
    mModelKeys = new HashMap<String, T>();
    // Look for all child events. We will then map them to our own internal ArrayList, which backs ListView
    mListener = this.mRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {

            T model = dataSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseListAdapter.this.mModelClass);
            mModelKeys.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(), model);

            // Insert into the correct location, based on previousChildName
            if (previousChildName == null) {
                mModels.add(0, model);
            } else {
                T previousModel = mModelKeys.get(previousChildName);
                int previousIndex = mModels.indexOf(previousModel);
                int nextIndex = previousIndex + 1;
                if (nextIndex == mModels.size()) {
                    mModels.add(model);
                } else {
                    mModels.add(nextIndex, model);
                }
            }
        }
```

**2. Descending query the data.**

The second way seams impossible to me, because when I searched on Firebase API documentation and on the web, I couldn't find anyway to order retraived data on descending way.

My data on firebase look like the following:

```
glaring-fire-9714 
    chat
        -Jdo7-l9_KBUjXF-U4_c
            author: Ahmed
            message: Hello World
        -Jdo71zU5qsL5rcvBzRl
            author: Osama
            message: Hi!
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why couldn't you do something like mFirebaseRef.orderByChild("key").limit(50) as described in this post: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries

Comment: @MichaelKrause I have tried that but it makes no deference. It sorts in Ascending way

Comment: You cannot change the sort order. But what you can change is whether it takes the first items (`limitToFirst`) or the last items (`limitToLast`). After that you can invert the items in your Java code. In fact, you *should* already be doing that, since later items may arrive out of order. Use the `previousChild` parameter to determine where the new item belongs in the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be to manually move the newly added data to the top of the `listview`. As you rightly noticed, new data added to a `listview` will automatically be appended to the bottom of the list, but you may freely move entries once they are added. Something like the following would help you manually move the newest entry to the top of the list:

```
int iSwapCount = listView.getCount() - 1;
int iPosition = listView.getCount() - 1;
for (int j = 0; j < iSwapCount; j++)
{
    Collections.swap(yourlistobject, iPosition, iPosition - 1);
    iPosition = iPosition - 1;
}
```

The above code will begin by calculating the number of swaps that will be required to move last list entry to the top of the list, which is determined by the number of elements in the list - 1. The same is true for calculating the last position in the list. From there `Collections.swap` will be used to swap the last element in the list with the element before it; this will be repeated until the last element is now the first element, with the rest of the entries in the list remaining in the same order. This code would have to be called each time a new entry is added so that the overall order of the list is maintained.

Comment: I am trying that but I have no Idea what is should I put instead of yourlistobject ?

Comment: The `yourlistobject` would be replaced with whatever your list is composed of. I am not familiar with the `ChatListAdapter` so I am not exactly sure what your list is composed of, but `Collections.swap` will swap elements within a `ListView` so pass whatever your list is comprised of to this method.

Comment: Can you please check the post again, I have edited the question with the FirebaseListAdapter ... I am sure that this is the place that I should edite

Answer (score 2):

I realize it has been a while since you asked but I had the same issue.  It does not appear that there is a direct answer here.

Here's the change to the firebase adapter to get new items on the top of the list.

Notice the change from add(...) to add(0,...) and add(next...) to add(prev...)

Look for comments:

```
                // prepend instead append
```

Example:

```
...

       // Insert into the correct location, based on previousChildName
        if (previousChildName == null) {
            mModels.add(0, model);
            mKeys.add(0, key);
        } else {
            int previousIndex = mKeys.indexOf(previousChildName);
            int nextIndex = previousIndex + 1;

            if (nextIndex == mModels.size()) {
                //mModels.add(model);
                //mKeys.add(key);

                // prepend instead append
                mModels.add(0,model);
                mKeys.add(0,key);
            } else {
                //mModels.add(nextIndex, model);
                //mKeys.add(nextIndex, key);

                // prepend instead append
                mModels.add(previousIndex, model);
                mKeys.add(previousIndex, key);

            }
        }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to invert a FirebaseUI list using a RecyclerView:

```
    boolean reverseList = true;
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, reverseList);
    if (reverseList) {
        manager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    }
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
```